# Devise and stored_location_for: how do you store the return location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise

I have a page whose path is (e.g.) /premises/92 on which I'm displaying "please [log in] or [register] for additional information" if the user is not logged in, and I want devise to return that same /premises/92 page after the user logs in.

I've read other posts and I think I understand how devise's `stored_location_for` is supposed to work.  In theory, I could put something like this in my `ApplicationController`:

```
def stored_location_for(resource)
  if (r = session[:return_to])
    session[:return_to] = nil
    r
  else
    super
  end
end
```

My question is: how / where do I set up session[:return_to]?

I want to set session[:return_to] only if the user clicks on [log in] or [register], but what's the best way to do that?

- Decorate the links with JavaScript?  That could work, but seems heavy-handed.
- Set it in the Premises Controller before rendering the page?  That doesn't seem right: what if the user doesn't click on the [log in] or [register] links?  Then I have session[:return_to] set to some odd value which might trip me up if the user logs in from some other page.
- Add a `?return_to=/premises/92` query string to the [log in] and [register] links, and detect that in the RegistrationsController and SessionsController and use that info to set up session[:return_to]?  That seems like it would work, but also heavy-handed.

None of these smell right.  What's the generally accepted technique for setting up state for stored_location_for?

Comment: How did the accepted answer help you decide **where** to set the return to url? Where did you do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Devise use

```
session["#{scope}_return_to"]
```

So you can use `session["user_return_to"]` if your model for authentication is User.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this answer works - it says what to change, but not where. As the OP says, is he supposed to add a ?param to all his links, and handle it on the controllers, or is that somehow taken care of magically by rails?

Comment: @kikito BTW I added 'def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session["user_return_to"] || home_view_path
  end' to my application_controller.rb file. When I want to set a return path i do it via `session["user_return_to"} = request.url` The home_view_path is specific to my app but everything else is pretty general. Just make sure that session variable isn't set if you don't want to redirect to it.

Comment: @kikito: this goes in your controller. You'd modify your session at whatever point it is that you know where you'd like to go back to. So, if you're rendering premises, including a login link, then you could set session[:user_return_to] = premise_path(@premise) in your PremisesController#show action.

Answer (score 9):

I found this whole devise redirect thing quite confusing.

Where @rorra says Devise uses `session["#{scope}_return_to"]`, he means that Devise default `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` will use that variable through the method `stored_location_for(resource)`.

So you should save the location you want to store in the variable `session["#{scope}_return_to"]`, which will usually be `session["user_return_to"]`. To do this place the following in your application_controller.rb:

```
after_action :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/password" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session["user_return_to"] = request.fullpath 
  end
end
```

In some cases you will not need to define an `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method as devise's default method will do all the redirects for you and if their is no redirect url available you will be redirected to the resource root path (usually user root path) and if that doesn't exist you will be redirected to the root path. If however, you would like to customise where the user is sent if there is no redirect url available, add the following to your application_contorller.rb (and change `root_path` accordingly):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
end
```

Answer (score 7):

`Devise` looks for the key `"#{resource}_return_to"` in the session.

Here I am quoting the API:

> By default, it first tries to find a valid `#{resource}_return_to` key in
>   the session, then it fallbacks to `#{resource}_root_path`, otherwise it
>   uses the `root_path`.

[Here is the link  to the API](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/frames)

Answer (score 4):

here's the best I could come up with. Works perfectly also with facebook authentication. by adding more restrictions to the prepending of urls to the session variable you can remove more and more paths you don't want the user to return too (e.g. callbacks, splash pages, landing pages, etc)

```
#ApplicationsController

after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  session[:previous_urls] ||= []
  # store unique urls only
  session[:previous_urls].prepend request.fullpath if session[:previous_urls].first != request.fullpath && request.fullpath != "/user" && request.fullpath != "/user/login" && request.fullpath != "/" && request.fullpath != "/user/logout" && request.fullpath != "/user/join" && request.fullpath != "/user/auth/facebook/callback"
  # For Rails < 3.2
  # session[:previous_urls].unshift request.fullpath if session[:previous_urls].first != request.fullpath 
  session[:previous_urls].pop if session[:previous_urls].count > 3
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
  @url = session[:previous_urls].reverse.first
  if @url != nil
    "http://www.google.com" + @url
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I do like this:

```
class ApplicationController < AC::Base
  after_filter :clear_attached_unit # UPDATED

  protected
  def clear_attached_unit
    session[:attached_unit_path] = nil unless keep_attached_unit_path?
  end

  def keep_attached_unit_path? # UPDATED
    @keep_attached_unit_path   
  end                           
end


class UnitController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :attach_unit, :only => [:show]

  protected
  def attach_unit
    session[:attached_unit_path] = request.url if request.get? && !request.xhr?
  end
end

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :keep_attached_unit_path! # UPDATED

  protected
  def keep_attached_unit_path! # UPDATED
    @keep_attached_unit_path = true
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User) && session[:attached_unit_path].present?
      session[:attached_unit_path]
    else
      super
    end
  end 
end
```

And extract this to module.

Comment: @anton: perhaps I'm missing something fundamental, but it appears that you are setting session[:attached_unit_path] before rendering /views/unit_controller/show.html.erb, right?  What happens if the user doesn't click on anything on that page and navigates to another path before signing in?  Doesn't that leave session[:attached_unit_path] incorrectly pointing back to the show page?

Comment: @fearless_fool You can clear the session[:attached_unit_path] in ApplicationController, right? ;) See update

Comment: @anton: don't take this the wrong way, but does that actually work? I'm no expert (that's why I'm asking here!) but it seems that: (1) UnitController#show sets :a_u_p, and (2) renders the unit_controller/show page, (3) user clicks on 'sign in', (4) ApplicationController's :before_filter clears the :a_u_p, (5) SessionsController#after_sign_in_path_for never gets to see :a_u_p.    Yes?  No?

Comment: @fearless_fool Oh, yes! Sorry, man. Then you should... see update :)

Comment: @anton: hey now -- is this code you actually use or not?  (am I debugging your code?? :)

Comment: @fearless_fool I use simple, first version of code. If user has gone to "show" page then to another and then to registration i redirect to first "show" page. For my app it's normaly