# Rails Devises Gem redirect on sign in redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having huge trouble trying to get [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to redirect to the user's previous page after signing in.

I have tried to follow [the guide on the Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) but when I implement this code it suggests:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)                                                                                                                      
  sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')                                            
  if request.referer == sign_in_url                                                                                                                    
    super                                                                                                                                                 
  else                                                                                                                                                    
    request.referer || "/"                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                     
end
```

It just always redirects to the root, and never to the previous page.

I've found [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330588/redirect-loop-with-devise-after-sign-in-path-for) with the same issue but the solutions in them have not worked.

I then thought I would simplify it and just return the user to the previous URL by getting just the path of the referal URL, as I thought that might help, however I get the same error with this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  URI(request.referer).path
end
```

It does work if I simply put a static path in:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  "/somepath"
end
```

That works absolutely fine. I'm sure I am missing something obvious here!

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028025/devise-and-stored-location-for-how-do-you-store-the-return-location

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104799/1657142.
As explained in the link, request.referer returns the HTTP_REFERER value set in the HTTP header. This value might be missing.