# Redirect after login using params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, redirect, parameters

Currently, when you login as a user, regardless of where from, you are taken to your homepage. I would like to check for params in the url and redirect based on that param.

Here's the code:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if params['redirect'] == 'SomeParameter'
      return special_url
    else
      return home_url
    end
end
```

If I use the regular login form with no params, I get taken to home_url. When I try to go to /user/login?redirect=SomeParameter, I still get taken to home_url. By the way, both routes are valid (if I just test special_url, it works just fine).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Does the home page redirect you to the login form if you aren't signed in?

Devise will store the page that you were on when you attempted to log in, and redirect to it when you log in.

This will take precedence over the after_sign_in_path_for, so if you are going Home page => Auto-redirect to Login => *log in*, then the return value of the after_sign_in_path_for doesn't matter.

If that is the case, you can play with stored_location_for ([Devise and stored_location_for: how do you store the return location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028025/devise-and-stored-location-for-how-do-you-store-the-return-location)) to alter where you go.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, you are of course correct. Still having issues. No, home doesn't require login. Here's what I have so far:

In the application controller I've got 
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        return params[:next] || super
    end

Then in the page's controller, I am setting the next param to "/someurl". I check the params and it's passed to the login page, but the redirect ignores it, just goes to super.

Comment: Is the method being called? Just insert "raise 'test'" or something in it to see :)